# Converting Point Feature to Latitude/Longitude Coordinate and GPX?

Tags: arcmap, gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude, gpx

I drew a point feature using the draw tool in ArcMap on a map in an area of interest. I am now interested in extracting the actual latitude/longitude of this point in geographic space so I can actually navigate to this exact area in a car. In addition, I am interested in determining how to export this as a GPX feature and inputting it directly into my Garmin GPS device.

Comment: First, in ArcMap, you can [convert your graphics into features](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/converting-graphics-into-features.htm), and then you will have more options to manupulate and convert your data. [Calculate geometry](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/calculating-area-length-and-other-geometric-properties.htm) is one way to fetch the coordinates of your point(s) and store them in the attribute table.

Answer (score 2):

**You can use this Features to GPX tool**
(Will be an ArcGIS Toolbox script)

https://github.com/arcpy/sample-gp-tools/tree/master/FeaturesToGPX

> Converts features (layers and feature classes of schema; point,
>   multipoint and polyline) into GPX files.
>
> Originally posted to ArcGIS.com as a sample, this tool is the sibiling
>   to the GPX to Features tool available in both ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap.
>
> Parameters Input Features | feature layer | required input
>
> Input featureclass or feature layer Output GPX | file | required
>   output
>
> Output GPX file to be created Zero dates (support Garmin Basecamp) |
>   boolean | optional input
>
> Create 0 date (JAN-1-1970). If a string field named 'DateTimeS'
>   exists, the values from this field will be used to populate the output
>   GPX file. If this field does not exist, an empty string is used for
>   the date. Garmin Basecamp software requires a valid date. Select this
>   option to insert the JAN-1-1970 (epoch) date into your output GPX file
>   if your features do not have a date field. Pretty output | boolean |
>   optional input *Format the output GPX file to be formatted in a nicer
>   way. ie. human readable. This does not impact hardware and software
>   devices ability to read the output file.
>
> General Usage The tool takes both points and line feature classes as
>   input.
>
> Line features will be turned into Tracks (TRKS)
>
> Point features will be turned into WayPoints (WPT)
>
> Note: GPX uses the WGS84 coordinate system. If the input data is not
>   in WGS84, the conversion to GPX will reproject the data. If a
>   transformation is required the best match possible is used. For
>   complete reprojection control you should run the Project tool,
>   converting your data into WGS84 and choosing the correct
>   transformation prior to creating a GPX file.

Comment: I'm a little unsure how this works--can I download this application? Thanks!

Comment: readme > https://github.com/arcpy/sample-gp-tools/blob/master/README.md (C:\downloads\sample-gp-tools>c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe setup.py install)

Comment: To download go to https://github.com/arcpy/sample-gp-tools and click 'clone or download' save the zip file.